# Can a periodically forced harmonic oscillator have a limit cycle?

Tags: dynamical-systems

My doubt is mostly regarding the time dependence.
And if the term is also applicable to higher dimensions. For example, two copies of the previous periodically forced harmonic oscillator.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Not really. There can be initial states where the solution is periodic with the period of the forcing, with others you get a mix of the eigenfrequency and the forcing frequency, or you get resonance. So you can get commensurable frequencies resulting in a periodic solution. Now if you add a dissipation/friction term to the DE, you can get something like a limit cycle based on the forcing with solutions converging to it.